# ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' to database (MySQL - MariaDB)

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

I'm currently making a simple app using Laravel and Xampp. While trying to connect the database and make migrations I got this error message from php artisan:

**PHP error**

[image: Php error]

So I decided to configure the database manually from the MySQL MariaDB shell (having started the session as the root user), but regardless of what user I try to gran privileges to on any database I get the following error:

**MariaDB error**

[image: MariaDB error]

The only possible reason I can come up with is the fact that there seems to be two different root user listed, but I don't thisnk this is the root of the problem, since I'm starting the shell as root, and not choosing one of these after starting.

**User List**

[image: User list]

I've already triple-checked my root user password (I've been starting the shell with this command mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1). Trying to do this through the PHP MyAdmin interface yields the same error.

I'd appreciate any insights, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The multiple entries for 'root' are specifying which host addresses are allowed connections from (127.0.0.1 and % respectively)

Your error appears to be because your configured database connection (in Laravel) is using the user 'usario'. Search your files for where `usario` is defined and input the proper credentials to connect to your database in its place.

This is a common error when credentias supplied to MySQL/MariaDB are simply invalid. Bad username, bad password, or both. In this instance it looks as though you're trying to run a migration with a user that doesn't exist.